# How to add an exception to a search query in R using grepl

Tags: regex, r

I have a variable consisting of different group names, which are responsible for terrorist incidents (observations).

I would like to exclude all observations, where this variable includes the word "Communist" e.g. exclude all cases where groupname = "Bangladesh Communist Party" etc. Here is my code for doing this:

```
newdata <- olddata[!grepl("Communist", olddata$groupname),]
```

But I want to add an exception to this rule: all the "Anti-Communist" groups should remain in the data frame. So the code should remove "Bangladesh Communist Party" but leave e.g. "Anti-Communist Rebels".

Do I use regular expressions? Or is there a way to add an exception to this kind of pattern matching? I guess it should look something like this at the end:

```
newdata <- olddata[!grepl("Communist"[but exclude "Anti-Communist"], olddata&groupname),]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [negative look behind](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+negative+look+behind):

```
x <- c("Bangladesh Communist Party", "Anti-Communist Rebels")
!grepl("(?<!Anti-)Communist", x,  perl = TRUE)
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```